# Conditionally replace cells in data frame based on another data frame

Tags: r

In the interest of learning better coding practices, can anyone show me a more efficient way of solving my problem? Maybe one that doesn't require new columns...

Problem: I have two data frames: one is my main data table (t) and the other contains changes I need to replace in the main table (Manual_changes). Example: Sometimes the CaseID is matched with the wrong EmployeeID in the file.

I can't provide the main data table, but the Manual_changes file looks like this:

```
Manual_changes = structure(list(`Case ID` = c(46605, 25321, 61790, 43047, 12157, 
16173, 94764, 38700, 41798, 56198, 79467, 61907, 89057, 34232, 
100189), `Employee ID` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 906572, 
164978, 145724, 874472, 654830, 846333, 256403), `Age in Days` = c(3, 
3, 3, 12, 0, 0, 5, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

temp = merge(t, Manual_changes, by = "Case ID", all.x = TRUE)
temp$`Employee ID.y` = ifelse(is.na(temp$`Employee ID.y`), temp$`Employee ID.x`, temp$`Employee ID.y`)
temp$`Age in Days.y`= ifelse(is.na(temp$`Age in Days.y`), temp$`Age in Days.x`, temp$`Age in Days.y`)
temp$`Age in Days.x` = NULL
temp$`Employee ID.x` = NULL
colnames(temp) = colnames(t)
t = temp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(t, Manual_changes, by = "Case ID") %>%
          mutate(Employee_ID.y = coalesce(`Employee ID.x`, `Employee ID.y`),
           `Age in Days.y` = coalesce(`Age in Days.x`, `Age in Days.y`))
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(t)[Manual_changes, 
   c('Employee ID', 'Age in Days') :=  
            .(fcoalesce(`Employee ID.x`, `Employee ID.y`),
                  fcoalesce(`Age in Days.x`, `Age in Days.y`)),

                on = .(`Case ID`)]
```

Comment: Hm, it seems this required me to make sure all the classes matched with their respective columns (changed everything to character), and then once I got the error to disappear, NAs were introduced. When there is an Employee ID.y, it still chooses Employee ID.x for its final value. If there is an value in the manual_changes, I want to replace it in the t. (with coalesce solution, will try data.table next)

Comment: @Gabriella I assumed that your columns are of the same type.  I couldn't test it without a small example

Comment: Yeah I thought so too, it seems there was a mix of numeric and character columns. I changed everything to character, but lost some data along the way. So the NAs are due to that. But I wonder why when there is both EID x and EID y, it chooses EID x instead of EID y?

Comment: @Gabriella your condition from code is that if one of them NA, choose the EID.x, similarly, in `coalesce` or `fcoalesce`, it choose based on the order of the arguments.  i.e. if the first one is non-NA, it choose that value in a particular row from the variable.  if the first is NA, and the second is non-NA, selects the second variable element

Comment: Understand (about the testing) and thanks for the explanation! I'll take a look at it later and try to troubleshoot - my data is probably too messy. Thank you for the help!